# Setup SonataNewsBundle to handle media in posts

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

Installed both SonataMediaBundle, SonataNewsBundle and SonataAdminBundle (and much more but these matter).

When posting a news item via the admin I choose to use the markdown configured as bellow.

```
sonata_formatter:
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
```

The formatter formats all titles etc. as expected however, media are not formatted. Though, I found some different document about the syntax non of them where parsed.

Formats found:

```
<% 1552362, 'gistfile1.txt'%>

<% media 4, 'small' %>
{% thumbnail 4, 'small' %}
```

So.

1. I could be wrong on the syntax
2. Some extra configuration is needed
3. Some custom coding needs to be done
4. Something should be done at the front end?
5. Or I am really missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<% media 4, 'small' %>` works correctly, however, you should make sure that your cache is cleared!