# SonataNewsBundle handle media in posts (html mode)

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

When creating new post by SonataNewsBundle in HTML mode, I dont see any option to link images/files/videos... from media.

I found this link ([Setup SonataNewsBundle to handle media in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562850/setup-sonatanewsbundle-to-handle-media-in-posts)) for markdown mode. But in HTML mode, How can I do this?

Anybody have ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way at the moment to import a `SonataMediaBundle` image media using the rich HTML editor.

You need to retrieve the public URL of your media, copy it, click the image button in the rich HTML editor and paste the image source URL.

I think that's the only solution at this time.